# After git add directory is empty

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-checkout

I am very new to git, I am using Ubuntu terminal to perform git actions.
After creating a git repository I executed the below commands

```
mkdir project

cd project

git init
```

then I copied all the files to project directory and executed

```
git add -A 
git commit 
git push origin master
```

Everything looks fine but it deleted all the files from my project directory.!! But all the files are safe in the server under master tag!!

Then I tried `git pull origin master` it says

```
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

Whats wrong with my steps? How can I pull the files?

Comment: no effect. It asked my password then exited.

Comment: did you use another command after pushing it to repo, it can not delete your files on its own, try git status and see what is there

Comment: git status lists all the files are deleted !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have deleted all your files by accident, do one thing

run:

> git stash

it will revert the working directory to HEAD commit,and you will get your files back.

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working.!! But I am sure I didn't deleted any files through terminal or explorer. I don't know what happen. I checked history, only git related commands are there. Anyway Thank you so much Siddarth for the quick response

Comment: checkout your terminal history to see all the commands that you have used, maybe you could find something there, happy to help :)

Comment: After your answer I checked, there is no deletion. But anyway it solved my issue